# how to create a semi circle ProgressBar in android

Tags: android, xml

I am developing a media player application in which I want the ProgressBar to be in the semi circle shape.I tried some xml files like Shape,rotate but it doesn't work.
What are the possible ways to change the shape of such progress bar??

Answer (score 1):

**res->drawable->progressbackground1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar1"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" />
```

**res->layout->main.xml**

```
  <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbackground1" />
```

**res->drawable->progressbar1.png**

[image]

Comment: In the main.xml it is showing the following error..                java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log